# Change the column name based on value in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a sql query for selecting data from table .In my table I have a status field.The status field having value 1 or 0. 1 -for new and 0 - for old. I want to change the return value based on the return value.

**TABLE**

```
filmname    year     ststus
........    .....    .......
film1       2014        1
```

**QUERY**

```
select filmname,year,status from film
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
filmname    year     ststus
........   ......    ......
film1       2014      New
```

here I getting status 1. and my need is to change the value to New while the status is 1 .how to change the value while executing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT filmname,year,
CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 'New' ELSE 'Old' END AS status 
FROM film
```